# Undefined offset: 3 error is thrown but error location is not shown

Tags: php, arrays, yii, runtime-error, offset

i am getting this error **Undefined offset: 3**

in brief the message is like this,

```
Internal Server Error
Undefined offset: 3

An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.

Thank you.
```

I would like to know from where does it happen or how to see the exact location of this issue so that i can easily go and resolve it.  i am using Yii framework but sadly it doesnt display me from where this error occurs.

Do i need to have php error logs enabled to see this ?

Comment: It look like array error, You need to debug the code. Based on the functionality you need to find the location to resolve this.

Comment: @Nes isnt it possible to know like from which line does this error occur ?

Comment: Basic i dont have idea on your code and functionality. So you are the person working on the functionality. You need to check the last functionality you worked in this.

Comment: @Nes no i was asking with the help of PHP error logs ?

Comment: No error log also have the same

Comment: Can u pls put ur advice as an answer below, so that i can accept it and make this close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal Server Error basically occurs on the server connection. And this seems some of the input missing to complete your functionality.

Basic i dont have idea on your code and functionality. So you are the person working on the functionality. You need to check the last functionality you worked in this.

Better to do the step by step debug process to resolve this.